# C++ public non-virtual base class method is inaccessible from sub-class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Given two class definitions in snippet 1 and 2 below, can you please tell me why I am getting the compilation errors shown in the 3rd snippet and how can I fix them? It looks the sub-class cannot access to the non-virtual public methods in base class (see the method getVipAddress in the subclass marked as line 197 in the 2nd code snippet). I am new to C++ realm, so I appreciate if you happen to see any other improvement needed in the code blocks.

**SNIPPET 1 (Base and Sub-class)**

**//BASE CLASS**

```
class BaseEntity
{
 public:
BaseEntity(): mUUID(""), mName("") {}
BaseEntity(std::string &uuid, std::string &name): mUUID(uuid), mName(name) { }

BaseEntity (const BaseEntity &copyin)
{
    this->mUUID = copyin.mUUID.c_str();
    this->mName = copyin.mName.c_str();
}

BaseEntity operator = (const BaseEntity &rhs)
{
    this->mUUID = rhs.mUUID.c_str();
    this->mName = rhs.mName.c_str();

    return *this;
}

~BaseEntity() { };

void setUUID(std::string uuid) { mUUID = uuid; }
void setName(std::string name) { mName = name; }

              /*LINE 89 is the following*/
const std::string &getUUID() const { return mUUID; }
const std::string &getName() const { return mName; }

  private:
std::string mUUID;
std::string mName;

};
```

**//SUBCLASS**

```
class VipAddressSet : BaseEntity
{
  public:
    VipAddressSet() : BaseEntity() { }
    VipAddressSet(std::string &uuid, std::string &name) : BaseEntity(uuid, name) { }

    VipAddressSet(const VipAddressSet &copyin)
    {
            setUUID(copyin.getUUID());
            setName(copyin.getName());

                std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::const_iterator iter;
            for( iter = copyin.mVipAddressList.begin(); iter !=  copyin.mVipAddressList.end(); iter++ )
            {

                addVipAddress(*iter);
            }
     }

     VipAddressSet operator = (const VipAddressSet &rhs)
     {
          setUUID(rhs.getUUID());
          setName(rhs.getName());

              std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::const_iterator iter;
          for( iter = rhs.mVipAddressList.begin(); iter != rhs.mVipAddressList.end(); iter++ )
              {
            addVipAddress(*iter);
          }

          return *this;
         }

     int getVipAddress(std::string &uuid, VipAddressEntity **ptr )
     {
        std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::const_iterator iter;
        for( iter = mVipAddressList.begin(); iter != mVipAddressList.end();  iter++ )
        {
   **/*~~~~ LINE 197 is the following ~~~~*/**
            if(iter->getUUID() == uuid)
            {
                **ptr = *iter;
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
     }


     const std::vector<VipAddressEntity>& getVipAddressList() const { return mVipAddressList; }


    private:
      std::vector<VipAddressEntity> mVipAddressList;

      void addVipAddress(const VipAddressEntity &entity)
      {
       mVipAddressList.push_back(entity);
      }

     };
```

**COMPILATION OUTPUT**

```
  $ g++ -g -c -std=c++11 -Wall Entity.hpp
  Entity.hpp: In member function ‘int  ECLBCP::VipAddressSet::getVipAddress(std::string&, ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity**)’:
  Entity.hpp:89:21: error: ‘const string& ECLBCP::BaseEntity::getUUID() const’ is inaccessible
  Entity.hpp:197:24: error: within this context
  Entity.hpp:197:24: error: ‘ECLBCP::BaseEntity’ is not an accessible base of ‘const   ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity’
```

Answer (score 7):

The default inheritance for a class is private. Change your declaration to

```
class VipAddressSet : public BaseEntity
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you must inherits it with public modifier

```
class VipAddressSet : public BaseEntity
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are inheriting with `private`. Try

```
 class VipAddressSet : public BaseEntity
```

otherwise the method won't be visible.